# How would you complete the pattern?

Tags: pattern

How would you complete this pattern?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> B

because

> There are 3 articles of the same type and colored clothing. Following a rule that there are 3 of each item, there would logically be 1 purple shirt, 1 pink hat and 1 blue pants remaining in the 3 by 3 grid

Answer (score 8):

Answer could also be

> C

because

> It looks like a font made of clothes, if you read it, it says 'unpuzzle(d)'

Comment: Nice catch. Might as well be the intended answer. Or might be part of one of those puzzles that reveals a character trait depending on which pattern you noticed.

Comment: But why is it a lowercase d? The L and E are uppercase. Was that flaw included to prevent it from being the clearly correct answer? Is it a hint that rationales exist that justify any of the six options as an answer? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Perhaps the answer is $D$ because, well, it's $D$.

Answer (score 2):

WarforgedMystic's answer is probably the intended one, but another answer can be justified.

Answer:

> A

because

> the grid would then contain 2 pink hats, 3 orange hats, 4 green hats; 2 purple shirts, 3 brown shirts, 4 blue shirts; 2 blue pants, 3 red pants, and 4 yellow pants.

Comment: Actually, WarforgedMystic's answer is the easy one... Refer to the title :)